# edit theme string variables on wordpress dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a website where weather parameters are very important. they are showing on every page and administrator should easy update them daily.

So it would be nice to have those four string variables on dashboard and then edit and save them.

Ss there a plugin way to add some string in dashboard and then output them in theme? or should i start learning how to write my first plugin?

Thanks for help.

**[edit]**
we have some plugins which can do that but the question is now:

**how to show admin plugin page as a widget on dashboard?**

Comment: Try this plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/options-framework/ or this: https://github.com/syamilmj/Options-Framework

Comment: i have found also: http://wordpress.org/plugins/just-wp-variables/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the solution is based on two plugins and some copy-paste action.

1. install: Just Variables plugin from http://wordpress.org/plugins/just-wp-variables/
2. make some variables on admin > settings > just variables
3. install Widget Builder from http://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-builder/
4. make new widget and copy-paste form from yourdomain.com/wp-admin/themes.php?page=jv_theme_vars
5. select "Available As Dashboard Widget", Save, and go to dashboard.

you can change value of inputs to variables output and this should go like this:

```
<form action="options.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="jv_theme_vars" name="option_page"/><input type="hidden" value="update" name="action"/><input type="hidden" value="ded28ad4c4" name="_wpnonce" id="_wpnonce"/><input type="hidden" value="/wp-admin/themes.php?page=jv_theme_vars" name="_wp_http_referer"/>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr valign="top">
            <th scope="row">Your Variable</th>
            <td><input type="text" style="width: 15em" name="jv_values[your_variable]" value="[justvar code="your_variable"]" class="regular-text"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Save" class="button button-primary" id="submit" name="submit"/></p>       
</form>
```

good luck. :)